# java orika complex mapping

Tags: java, mapping, orika

I use Orika and I want map `codeActivite1.value` from `Value.class` to `tasks.tasks[0].notes` of `Ligne.class`

```
mapperFactory.classMap(Value.class, Ligne.class).field().field("codeActivite1.value", "tasks.tasks[0].notes").register();

public class Value {
    @SerializedName("code_activite1")
    private CodeActivite1 codeActivite1;
    //getter setter
}

public class CodeActivite1 {
    @SerializedName("value")
    private String value;
    //getter setter
}

public class Ligne {
    private Tasks tasks;
    //getter setter
}

public class Tasks{
    private Task[] tasks;
    //getter setter
}

public class Task {
    private String notes;
    //getter setter
}

ma.glasnost.orika.MappingException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.String is an unsupported source class for constructing instances of com.xxxx.business.xxxx.bean.Task[]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem when I change array by List to Tasks.class

```
public class Tasks {
    private List<Task> tasks;
    //getter setter
}

mapperFactory.classMap(Value.class, Ligne.class).field().field("codeActivite1.value", "tasks.tasks[0].notes").register();
```